# Csv как удалить текущую строку

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, telegram-bot, csv

Пишу бота который будет каждый раз заходить проверять мой файл csv, и если там что то записано , то отправлять и потом  удалять из csv файла то что отправил, и еще в этот файл будет заходить другой бот который как раз будет записывать данные, можно ли так сделать?

вот код

```
import csv
import telebot 
import os
import time 


bot = telebot.TeleBot("API")
time.sleep(5)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def start(message):  
    time.sleep(6)
    while True:
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Проверка началась")
      with open('users.csv') as File:
        reader = csv.reader(File)
      
        for row in reader:
          time.sleep(5)
          print(row)

          bot.send_message(message.chat.id,(row))
        
        
        
        
bot.polling()
```

Comment: пробуйте построчно удалять строки после отправки сообщений, подобную тему поднимали тут: [ссылка](https://overcoder.net/q/70856/использование-python-для-удаления-определенной-строки-в-файле)

Comment: *можно ли так сделать?* Нет, нельзя. Это почти наверняка приведёт к разрушению данных. Либо нужно открывать его эксклюзивно, быстренько перезаписывать (всё от начала изменяемой строки до конца) и закрывать. Обоим ботам.

Comment: Используйте лучше базу данных, причём лучше не удалять данные, а отмечать в каком-то поле, что действие выполнено. Если база будет сильно пухнуть, то удалять из неё периодически старые записи отдельной задачей.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно предотвратить возможность одновременного открытия файла двумя ботами. Для проверки использования файла можно использовать следующую функцию. Тестировалось только на linux.

```
import psutil


def has_handle(fpath):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            for item in proc.open_files():
                if fpath == item.path:
                    return True
        except Exception:
            pass

    return False
```

Если файл используется другим процессом, функция вернет True. Функцией должны пользоваться оба бота. Но я не думаю, что даже эта проверка на 100% предотвратит одновременный доступ к файлу.

А вообще, я бы использовал брокера для передачи сообщения между ботами, тем более что нет необходимости хранить данные.